# JQuery Datatables Search Issues

Tags: jquery, search, datatables

I am new to stackoverflow.

I am using jquery datatables. I encountered a problem when using its search feature. I added each row with an edit button, and the event is triggered using javascript. My script for the edit button is working fine until I use the searchbox to look for a particular item. After the result is generated, the edit button doesn't work anymore.

May someone tried or experienced this one.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use datatables function [fnDrawCallback](http://datatables.net/usage/callbacks):

```
"fnDrawCallback": function( oSettings ) {
    //put some code here for add buttons
}
```

This function is fire after every draw datatables content - on initialization, after sorting/filtering